# Identity server 4 strange behavior, not redirecting back to the mvc client after login

Tags: identityserver4

Using aspnetcore 2.1and Identity Server 4 quickstart, I have setup a token server with an mvc client so that when the AuthorizeAttribute is used it redirects to the ID4 server login screen and after logging in it redirects back to the mvc client.

Since we were refactoring an old application with custom salt and hash in the database I have created a custom user store, role store and password hasher.

I can login fine using

signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync()

but it does not redirect back to the client as I would expect.

From the fiddler log i can see it redirects to /connect/authorize/callback then back to the login page.At which point the user is clearly logged in because the user name appears with the option to logout.I put in a breakpoint on the login get action and see that User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is true.

For testing I swapped the login method for the login action method from the is4inmem template which uses

HttpContext.SignInAsync(user.SubjectId, user.Username, props)

at which point it does redirect back to the client.

Am I missing some part of the custom userstore which _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync calls to log users in the same way as HttpContext.SignInAsync?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the config ready to paste here I relised that I had this line commented out:

builder.AddAspNetIdentity();

When I uncommented that it worked perfectly.